# Getting 415 for a postman request in rest assured having form data as body

Tags: postman, rest-assured

I am trying to pass the following PUT request but I am getting 415 instead of 200. The request contains Form data and is passing in Postman but failing in Rest assured.

```
        ValidatableResponse response = given().header("Authorization", token)
                .header("Content-type", "application/json")
                .contentType("multipart/form-data")
                .multiPart("indexCalendarDateOverrideRequest", "{\n" +
                        "    \"comments\": \"Test\",\n" +
                        "    \"indexCalendarDateOverrideMap\": {\n" +
                        "        \"CUTOFF_CAL\": [\n" +
                        "            {\n" +
                        "                \"calendarDate\": \"2024-02-28\",\n" +
                        "                \"isBusinessDay\": true,\n" +
                        "                \"isMonthEndBusinessDay\": false,\n" +
                        "                \"isHoliday\": false,\n" +
                        "                \"isWeekend\": false,\n" +
                        "            }\n" +
                        "        ]\n" +
                        "    }\n" +
                        "}\n")
                .multiPart("files", "[]").log().all()
                .put(EndPoint.UPDATE_CALENDAR_DAYS).then().log().all();
        response.assertThat().statusCode(200);
```

The postman request cURL I am trying to automate is as follows

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://calculation-stg.us-west-2.mi4cd87.easn.mo.com/mat-data/index-cal/dates/update/days' \
--header 'accept: */*' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
--form 'indexCalendarDateOverrideRequest="{
    \"comments\": \"Test\",
    \"indexCalendarDateOverrideMap\": {
        \"CUTOFF_CAL\": [
            {
                \"calendarDate\": \"2024-02-22\",
                \"isBusinessDay\": true,
                \"isMonthEndBusinessDay\": false,
                \"isHoliday\": false,
                \"isWeekend\": false,
                \"holiday\": false,
                \"weekend\": false,
                \"businessDay\": true,
                \"monthEndBusinessDay\": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
";type=application/json' \
--form 'files="[]";type=multipart/form-data'
```